# Problem in converting from for-comprehension to map

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I'm trying to convert a Scala `for comprehension` into using `map` and I'm running into a problem.

For illustration, consider that following conversion that works as expected.

```
scala> for (i <- 0 to 10) yield i * 2
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)

scala> 0 to 10 map { _ * 2 }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
```

However, the following isn't working.  What mistake am I making?

```
scala> import util.Random
import util.Random

scala> for (i <- 0 to 10) yield Random.nextInt(10)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(3, 0, 7, 5, 9, 4, 6, 6, 6, 3, 0)

scala> 0 to 10 map { Random.nextInt(10) }
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Int => ?
       0 to 10 map { Random.nextInt(10) }
                                   ^
```

The root cause might be either my inability to correctly decipher the error message or fixing the cause.  As I review the signature of `Random.nextInt` it seems to be returning an `Int`.

```
scala> Random.nextInt
   def nextInt(n: Int): Int   def nextInt(): Int
```

Error message is saying that I need to provide a function that takes an `Int` and returns "something" (not sure what `?` stands for).

```
required: Int => ?
```

So I can see that there is a mismatch.  But how do I convert what I want to happen -- a call to `Random.nextInt(10)` -- into a function and pass it to `map`?

Any help in understanding the error message below would be appreciated.

```
scala> 0 to 10 map { Random.nextInt(10) }
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Int => ?
       0 to 10 map { Random.nextInt(10) }
                                   ^
```

(Edit)

Doing the following helped.

```
scala> def foo(x: Int): Int = Random.nextInt(10)
foo: (x: Int)Int

scala> 0 to 10 map { foo }
res10: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5, 1, 6, 0, 7, 4)
```

But comments on this or suggestions of recommended Scala-way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Int => ?` in the error message means than the compiler expects to see a function from `Int` to some other type (`?`). But `Random.nextInt(10)` is not a function, it's just an `Int`. You have to take an integer parameter:

```
0 to 10 map { i => Random.nextInt(10) }
```

You can also explicitly ignore the argument:

```
0 to 10 map { _ => Random.nextInt(10) }
```

or, even better, just use `fill`:

```
Vector.fill(10){ Random.nextInt(10) }
```